# How do you "debug" a regular expression with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, debugging, sed

I'm trying to use a regexp using `sed`. I've tested my regex with kiki, a gnome application to test regexpd, and it works in kiki.

```
date: 2010-10-29 14:46:33 -0200;  author: 00000000000;  state: Exp;  lines: +5 -2;  commitid: bvEcb00aPyqal6Uu;
```

I want to replace `author: 00000000000;` with nothing. So, I created the regexp, that works when I test it in kiki:

```
author:\s[0-9]{11};
```

But doesn't work when I test it in `sed`.

```
sed -i "s/author:\s[0-9]{11};//g" /tmp/test_regex.txt
```

I know regex have different implementations, and this could be the issue. My question is: how do I at least try do "debug" what's happening with sed? Why is it not working?

Comment: I have found that when using sed with a substitution and you want to debug the "find" portion, it helps to first get the regex right in grep. Because grep makes it clear whether it matches and if not you can troubleshoot, and can delete from the right hand side till it matches and troubleshoot building it up , seeing what matches. You could use another tool to test, i see you used one called kiki. How about using grep, you may find that with the right switch on it and sed, you get the same implementation. like GNU ERE or something.

Comment: See also: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My version of `sed` doesn't like the `{11}` bit. Processing the line with:

```
sed 's/author: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];//g'
```

works fine.

And the way I debug it is exactly what I did here. I just constructed a command:

```
echo 'X author: 00000000000; X' | sed ...
```

and removed the more advanced regex things one at a time:

- used `<space>` instead of `\s`, didn't fix it.
- replaced `[0-9]{11}` with 11 copies of `[0-9]`, that worked.

It pretty much *had* to be one of those since I've used every other feature of your regex before with `sed` successfully.

But, in fact, this *will* actually work without the hideous 11 copies of `[0-9]`, you just have to escape the braces `[0-9]\{11\}`. I have to admit I didn't get around to trying that since it worked okay with the multiples and I generally don't concern myself too much with brevity in `sed` since I tend to use it more for quick'n'dirty jobs :-)

But the brace method *is* a lot more concise and adaptable and it's good to know how to do it.

Comment: I think leaving off \s as space also helped this.

Comment: I tried to escape '{' and '}': sed -i "s/author:\s[0-9]\{11\};//g" /tmp/test_regex.txt. It worked. Would you mind testing?

Comment: @Peer, actually, I put that back in and it still worked. That's not to say it will work on _every_ `sed` (mine is the CygWin one).

Comment: Thanks for answering and helping me out. I used to hate these tools, I think I just need some more training and study and get used to these little issues, and learn to do baby steps.

Answer (score 24):

In sed you need to escape the curly braces. `"s/author:\s[0-9]\{11\};//g"` should work.

Sed has no debug capability.  To test you simplify at the command line iteratively until you get something to work and then build back up.

command line input:

```
$ echo 'xx a: 00123 b: 5432' | sed -e 's/a:\s[0-9]\{5\}//'
```

command line output:

```
xx  b: 5432
```

Comment: The posting software ate my backslashes! Put a backslash before your opening and closing curly braces.

Comment: I fixed up your answer. If you put backticks around code, it will leave it alone (first line above). If you indent lines with four spaces, you get the same effect for code blocks (bottom section).

Answer (score 21):

There is a Python script called `sedsed` by Aurelio Jargas which will show the stepwise execution of a `sed` script. A debugger like this isn't going to help much in the case of characters being taken literally (e.g. `{`) versus having special meaning (e.g. `\{`), especially for a simple substitution, but it will help when a more complex script is being debugged.

[The latest SVN version](http://code.google.com/p/sedsed/source/browse/).
[The most recent stable release](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/).
<sup><sub>*Disclaimer: I am a minor contributor to `sedsed`.*</sub></sup>

[image: sedsed example]

Another `sed` debugger, [`sd`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/sd.sh.txt) by Brian Hiles, written as a Bourne shell script (I haven't used this one).

Comment: Recent versions of sed now have a similar `--debug` option.

Comment: @liberforce: Cool! It [came in](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=3ac640ce3b896db8605adc25c266334c1fd455dc) with GNU sed [4.6](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/NEWS). `sort` and `date` now have `--debug` options, too!

Comment: Actually answers the question

Answer (score 17):

You have to use the -r flag for extended regex:

```
sed -r 's/author:\s[0-9]{11};//g'
```

or you have to escape the {} characters:

```
sed 's/author:\s[0-9]\{11\};//g'
```

Comment: `sed -r` is my favourite option as well: clearer to read the patterns as parenthesis and many other have to be escaped otherwise...

Comment: sed -E for extended regex makes it very easy to express your ideas via regular expressions  patterns

Comment: `-r` is for GNU `sed`, `-E` is for BSD (MacOS) `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to debug a `sed` command, you can use the `w` (write) command to dump which lines `sed` has matched to a file.

From `sed manpages`:

> Commands which accept address ranges
>
> (...)
>
> > w filename
> >
> > > Write the current pattern space to filename.

---

## Applying to your question

Let's use a file named **sed_dump.txt** as the sed dump file.

1) Generate the sed dump:

```
sed "/author:\s[0-9]{11};/w sed_dump.txt" /tmp/test_regex.txt
```

2) Check file **sed_dump.txt** contents:

```
cat sed_dump.txt
```

**Output:**

> 

*It's empty...*

3) Trying to escape '{' regex control character:

```
sed "/author:\s[0-9]\{11\};/w sed_dump.txt" /tmp/test_regex.txt
```

4) Check file **sed_dump.txt** contents:

```
cat sed_dump.txt
```

**Output:**

> date: 2010-10-29 14:46:33 -0200;  author: 00000000000;  state: Exp;  lines: +5 -2;  commitid: bvEcb00aPyqal6Uu;

### Conclusion

In step 4), a line has been matched, this means that `sed` matched your pattern in that line. It does not guarantee the correct answer, but it's a way of debugging using `sed` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the -i flag incorrectly. You need to put give it a string to put on the temporary file. You also need to escape your curly braces.

```
sed -ibak -e "s/author:\s[0-9]\{11\};//g" /tmp/test_regex.txt
```

I usually debug my statement by starting with a regex I know will work (like 's/author//g' in this case). When that works I know that I have the right arguments. Then I expand the regex incrementally.

Comment: I tested with \{ in paxdiablo's answer. It's working, I just wanted to know if it's going to work in his environment too. I understood the incrementally regex approach from paxdiablo as well, seens to be a good one.

Comment: `-i` does not _need_ a suffix and, when you use it, it's either `-ibak` or `--in-place=bak`, never `-i=bak`. I won't downvote since it's trivial but you may want to fix it.

Comment: fixed the -i suffix, the old way works fine, it just put some extra chars on the suffix. There are some versions of sed that will not make a temporary file if you do not supply a suffix. This is dangerous and can cause data corruption.

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like a perl regex than it does a sed regex. Perhaps you would prefer using

```
perl -pi.orig -e 's/author:\s[0-9]{11};//g' file1 file2 file3
```

At least that way you could always add `-Mre=debug` to debug the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are substituting `author: 00000000000` is already said in `sed` when you add the `s` before the first `/`.

Comment: But it's not working. author: 00000000000 doesn't get substituted with the line I provided.

Comment: What is not working? I did not provide an example but an answer on why your regexp did not work. In paxdiablo's answer you will find the right command for sed.

Comment: author: 00000000000 doesn't gets substituted, so the regex is not working. Thanks anyway.