# sed is not working with somewhat complex replacement string

Tags: sed

Why does this sed does not work?

```
sed 's/DIRS = \[\]/ DIRS = \[os.path.join\(BASE_DIR, \'templates\',\'allauth\',\'account\'\)\]/' settings.py
```

running this just gives a ">" prompt (as if something is unterminated).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052253/how-do-you-debug-a-regular-expression-with-sed

Comment: [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/3266847)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of your usage with `’` and `()`.

Although I don’t underdstand why have you complicated the expression so much, just use:

```
sed "s/DIRS = \[\]/ DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates','allauth','account')]/" settings.py
```

Comment: Notice that this relies on the shell not removing ``\`` within double quotes when followed by `[`. The safe way (that doesn't require knowing which characters following ``\`` leave it unchanged) would be `\\[\\]`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., I am not sure about this, doesn’t he want to replace `DIRS = []` so he escaped them `[` and `]`?

Comment: Yes, but within double quotes, shell escaping takes place before sed gets to see your string, and certain characters following the ``\`` make it disappear - `[` and `]` happen to not be among them, though.